# LLM-AI useful in chaffing?

Tags: encryption

Greetings from a newbie and crypto ignaramus. I hope that this is an appropriate forum for this question - please advise if not, or feel free to move it to another SE section.

First heard of chaffing years ago when government agencies were trying to ban PGP etc. from civilian use, especially internationally. With computing power and bandwidth so cheap now, it seems more practical than in dial-up days.

I'm wondering if LLMs like ChatGPT might easily be customized as efficient vehicles for turning plaintext into chaffed messages seamless, and with such lexical and syntactic authenticity that they would be diifuclt even to identify as containing a payload? And with more than 50k words as "primitives" - not to mention current colloquialisms, slang and the numerous specialized vocabularies of diverse fields - might it even be possible to layer multiple messages, essentially coded orthogonally so that words or phrased might be used to include multiple secret messages in one big package?

Perhaps this is already being done?

Thanks - just curious.